# Unify Circuit OAuth2 - Why does Body return empty [] from REST API requests?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, circuit-sdk

When I try REST API's with my oauth 2.0's token I keep getting back empty results [] under the body with OK-200 status codes in the headers.

I created a bot and tested the rest API's with curl + basic authentication and also with swagger and they work fine. I tested my curl command using oauth 2.0 with the swagger token and this works fine as well.

I tried different settings to test, but to stick with a basis:

- I created a Bot under custom apps, Scopes are 'All' selected and TTL is 'Forever'.
- I requested and received my token successfully via REST with the following scopes:'READ_USER_PROFILE,WRITE_USER_PROFILE,READ_CONVERSATIONS,WRITE_CONVERSATIONS,READ_USER'.
- I noticed that 'ALL' scope doesn't work, it returns "invalid_client, The Application null  is not enabled for scope ::=[ALL]", but the same client works without any of the scopes above mentioned together or on their own except 'ALL'.
- I made sure I had the necessary scopes for the REST APIs I was testing, e.g. 'READ_CONVERSATIONS' for "/conversations"
- I don't receive any 401 or other error codes at all, just 200's.
- I tested the same commands with the token generated by swagger and that one returns the body string with results (in other words, this token works)
- I have replicated this same problems with Postman and PowerShell's Invoke-WebRequest/Invoke-RestMethod.
- Not sure if it's related, but I noticed the "OAuth Apps" options no longer exist in the web app: webclient under "Administration" > "OAuth Apps". "OAuth Apps" tab, enable "OAuth Apps" in "Settings" > "Circuit Labs".

```
\\Requesting token:
curl -X POST https://circuitsandbox.net/oauth/token -d "client_id=myclientidhere&client_secret=myclientsecrethere&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=READ_USER_PROFILE,WRITE_USER_PROFILE,READ_CONVERSATIONS,WRITE_CONVERSATIONS,READ_USER" -i

{"access_token":"myaccesstokenhere","token_type":"Bearer","scope":["READ_USER_PROFILE","WRITE_USER_PROFILE","READ_CONVERSATIONS","WRITE_CONVERSATIONS","READ_USER"]}

\\Making request:
curl -i "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations" -H "Authorization: Bearer myaccesstokenhere" -i
[]
```

```
\\\Full sample (-i parameter):
\\Requesting token:
curl -X POST https://circuitsandbox.net/oauth/token -d "client_id=myclientidhere&client_secret=myclientsecrethere&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=READ_USER_PROFILE,WRITE_USER_PROFILE,READ_CONVERSATIONS,WRITE_CONVERSATIONS,READ_USER" -i

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 01:21:43 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 179
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Accept-Language, User-Agent, Origin, Connection, Host, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Type, api_key, apiKey
ETag: W/"b3-K441G+yOERm+Qhj2E8VpkzO8ISg"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000; includeSubdomains; preload

{"access_token":"myaccesstokenhere","token_type":"Bearer","scope":["READ_USER_PROFILE","WRITE_USER_PROFILE","READ_CONVERSATIONS","WRITE_CONVERSATIONS","READ_USER"]}

\\Making request:
curl -i "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations" -H "Authorization: Bearer myaccesstokenhere"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 01:25:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Accept-Language, User-Agent, Origin, Connection, Host, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Type, api_key, apiKey
ETag: W/"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000; includeSubdomains; preload

[]
```

I expect the output to include the body output for the request, e.g.

```
{"type":"COMMUNITY","convId":"5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","participants":["5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f"],"topic":"YourCompany","creationTime":1560992185888,"modificationTime":1561143383261,"creatorId":"5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","creatorTenantId":"5fad5fa4-1097-d66f-083a-3f129214e99f","description":"Default open conversation for YourCompanyHere"}
```

But the actual output is: `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested that and I get the conversations (and communities) returned.This will not return your conversations, but the conversations the bot is a member of.  Make sure the bot is a member of a conversation.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks! That helped a lot, however it didn't work straight away with me just adding the bot to the conversation, still got blanks back, reason why I was using the same e-mail for the sandbox and the bot. I will elaborate in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the response above, that was part of what I was missing, I still got blanks back even after adding the bot to the conversation. I also faced all kind of weird problems, e.g. receiving errors when trying to add the old bot to new conversations etc. The reason why is because I was using the same e-mail address for my circuit sandbox account and for the bot, so that probably created conflict. In short, this is what worked for me:

**1. Created new bot with a different e-mail address than my sandbox account (even a fake e-mail works)**

**2. Added bot to the conversation via e-mail address (bot name didn't pull it up)** - Thanks @Roger

**3. Ran same commands to create token and use API's, this time it succeeded!**

Help figuring it out, issue and fix reproed by a colleague in a different sandbox (Thanks Ricky El-Qasem!), tested in postman, curl and PowerShell.

Comment: It should not be possible to create a bot with an email that is already used in the system. Can you explain how to managed to have the same email for your user account on the sandbox and also for the bot?

Comment: Hi Roger, I just followed the same flow as usual, I do remember getting an error and I just moved the options around (which shouldn't make a difference) and it suddenly did, I tried to replicate but I get the expected error (Unable to create app), so I can't repro, I also deleted that bot last week, however 
both me and a colleague had that exact same problem with the blanks, I'll check with him and get back, perhaps he hasn't deleted the old bot.